# Cant execute script function myFunction from another function

Tags: javascript, html, function

```
function editBaancode() {
  var baan1 = "<div class='dropdown'>";
  var baan2 = "<button onclick=myFunction() class='dropbtn'>Dropdown</button>";
  var baan4 = "<div id='myDropdown' class='dropdown-content'>";
  var baan5 = "<div id='myDropdown' class='dropdown-content'><input type='text' placeholder='Search..' id='myInput' onkeyup=filterFunction()";
  var baan7 = "><a>About</a>";
  var baan8 = "<a>Base</a>";
  var baan9 = "<a>Blog</a>";
  var baan10 = "<a href=#>CREATE</a>";
  var baan11 = "</div>";
  var baan12 = "</div>";
  var res = baan1.concat(baan1, baan2, baan4, baan5, baan7, baan8, baan9, baan10, baan11, baan12);
  document.getElementById('mylocation').innerHTML = res;
}
```

Comment: Please offer the error message

Comment: Check for error messages in web browsers console.

Answer (score 0):

see working link here -> are you doing in the same way which is herein
[jsbin](https://output.jsbin.com/kecutuheqa/)

```
function editBaancode(){var n="<div class='dropdown'>",o=n.concat(n,"<button onclick=myFunction() class='dropbtn'>Dropdown</button>","<div id='myDropdown' class='dropdown-content'>","<div id='myDropdown' class='dropdown-content'><input type='text' placeholder='Search..' id='myInput' onkeyup=filterFunction()","><a>About</a>","<a>Base</a>","<a>Blog</a>","<a href=#>CREATE</a>","</div>","</div>");document.getElementById("mylocation").innerHTML=o}function myFunction(){alert("executing on button click")}window.onload=function(){editBaancode()};
```

Comment: I want to do it the below way https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown_filter